Which structure for user profile fields checkboxes or entry relations?
I have a need for user profiles to store options form a list of 100 checkbox points.
These will need to be searchable facets later.
Each check box value also will need to be a content url in the front.
Eg
User -> fruit field checkboxes apples,oranges,plums,pears etc
Or
User -> fruit entry relations with entries apples,oranges,plums,pears etc
From a user choice UX pov choosing which thy will do only once checkboxes seems to make a better option. However from a content seo url perspective entries make more sense to me.
Has anyone experience of this and what route did you choose?
Does the craft user model have any downsides vs the craft entry model?
tia

Have you considered using categories mate? It depends, of course, on how you plan to use the relations, but categories might be a good fit. You can predefine your category group of 'fruits' and then add a simple category select field to the user, which will allow you to easily query users for related 'fruits' and vice-versa. Categories can have URLs and are often easier to work with than entries in terms of user permissions / visiblility, etc. Of course ’it depends…‘
